# Send raw message with mailx command

Tags: mailx, mail-command

How can I pass a full raw/MIME message (raw file) to the Linux mailx command for delivery? I don't want to extract the recipient, subject, body etc from the message - I want to feed a complete existing raw mail message 'as is' to mailx for sending whilst retaining all existing headers.

An example message is as follows:

```
Received: (qmail 32389 invoked by uid 0); 13 Jun 2017 09:24:51 -0400
Date: Tue, 13 Jun 2017 09:24:51 -0400
From: root@test.server.com
To: test@test.com
Subject: Test Email
Message-ID: <593fe7a3.IgSR+/BLy+NYXlVZ%root@test.server.com>
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.5 7/5/10
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

The test mail content
```

So I want to be able to feed the above to the mailx command on the command line.

The purpose of this is to make the server deliver the original message (exactly as it was read from the raw message file) via a secondary SMTP server - to do this we would use mailx's -S switch to specify the secondary SMTP server eg:

```
mailx -S smtp="backup-mail-server.com:25" < feed in the MIME message here somehow
```

How can I do this with `mailx`?

Comment: Then why do you bother with `mailx`?  Use `sendmail -t`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura can you send the message through an external SMTP server with sendmail? That's why I was intending to use mailx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 mailx -S smtp="backup-mail-server.com:25" < mailx -p -f /var/mail/nobody
```

This will read the RAW mail file, and pipe it into your send.